# Combo Box In Extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

my combo boxes are not displaying when i click on add occurs a new row but it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xtype' of undefined" error every time and not showing the combo box.please help me to solve this problem.it works fine in extjs 3 but i am currently working on extjs 4

```
 var cond1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                                  fields: ['maint_condition1'],
                                                   data : [
                                                            ['Excellent'],['Poor'],['New'],['good'],['scrap']       
                                                          ]
                                                }
                            );
    var cond2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                                  fields: ['maint_condition2'],
                                                   data : [
                                                            ['Excellent'],['Poor'],['New']
                                                          ]
                                                }
                            );


    var cond3 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                                  fields: ['maint_condition3'],
                                                   data : [
                                                            ['New'],['Excellent']
                                                          ]
                                                }
                            );

    var cond4 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                                  fields: ['maint_condition4'],
                                                   data : [
                                                            ['New'],['Excellent'],['good'],['Poor'],['scrap']
                                                          ]
                                                }
                            );

//ready store
     //var  cb_select2 =new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();
    //var cb_select2 =new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();
    var asset_edit = new Ext.form.TextField();
    var notes_edit = new Ext.form.TextField();
    var date_edit = new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'm/d/Y'});
    var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    saveText: 'Save',
    listeners: {
                afteredit: syncStore
               }
    });
    var cond1_edit = new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'combo'});
    //var sm = Ext.grid.getSelectionModel();  
//Grid for show data


   var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    //renderTo: 'grid1',
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    plugins:[rowEditing],
    frame: true,
    height:140,
    width:950,
    enableColumnMove: false,
    store: store,
    columns: [
                {header: "Asset ID", dataIndex: 'asset_id',readOnly: true},
                {header: "Maint. ID", dataIndex: 'id',readOnly: true},
                {header: "Date", dataIndex: 'date_',xtype: 'datecolumn',width: 90,
                                    editor: {
                                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                           allowBlank: false,
                                               format: 'm/d/Y',
                                             minValue: '01/01/2006',
                                              minText: 'Cannot have a start date before the company existed!',
                                             maxValue: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y')
                                            }

                },
                {header: "Notes", dataIndex: 'notes',editor: notes_edit},
                {header: "Maint_condition1", dataIndex: 'maint_condition1', sortable: true,width: 120,
                          editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                                                         xtype:'combobox',
                                                         allowBlank: false,
                                                         mode: 'local',
                                                         store: cond1,
                                                         valueField: 'maint_condition1',
                                                         displayField: 'maint_condition1',
                                                         triggerAction: 'all',
                                                         editable: false
                                                         }
                                                        )},
                {header: "Maint_condition2", dataIndex: 'maint_condition2', sortable: true,width: 120,
                          editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                                                              xtype:'combobox',
                                                         allowBlank: false,
                                                         mode: 'local',
                                                         store: cond2,
                                                         valueField: 'maint_condition2',
                                                         displayField: 'maint_condition2',
                                                         triggerAction: 'all',
                                                         editable: false
                                                         }
                                                        )},
                {header: "Maint_condition3", dataIndex: 'maint_condition3', sortable: true,width: 120,
                         editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                                                             xtype:'combobox',
                                                        allowBlank: false,
                                                        mode: 'local',
                                                        store: cond3,
                                                        valueField: 'maint_condition3',
                                                        displayField: 'maint_condition3',
                                                        triggerAction: 'all',
                                                        editable: false
                                                        }
                                                      )},
                {header: "Maint_condition4", dataIndex: 'maint_condition4', sortable: true,width: 120,
                         editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                                                              xtype:'combobox',
                                                         allowBlank: false,
                                                         mode: 'local',
                                                         store: cond4,
                                                         valueField: 'maint_condition4',
                                                         displayField: 'maint_condition4',
                                                         triggerAction: 'all',
                                                         editable: false
                                                        }
                                                      )}
                ],

          tbar: [
            {
             text: 'Add Record',
             icon: 'http://localhost/toolbar2/app/webroot/images/table_add.png',
              cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
          handler: function() 
                 {
                rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                 var r = Ext.create('User', {
                               id: 0,
                            notes: 'New Notes',
                         asset_id: window.id,           
                });
                     store.insert(0, r);
                    rowEditing.startEdit(0,0);
                  }
             },
             {
              text: 'Remove Record',
              icon: 'http://localhost/toolbar2/app/webroot/images/table_delete.png',
               cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
           handler: function() {
                var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                store.remove(sm.getSelection());
                if (store.getCount() > 0) 
                {
                 sm.select(0);
                }

            }
        }]

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on my last comment on your other question - you need to define datatypes in the store - aka the xtype. Your code won't just know the items are strings unless you implicit define it.

Comment: And the other one - you don't need 'xtype' inside comboboxes creation - you already are using Ext.create with specific type.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I solved this xtype error and combo box also coming properly..now just jeson decode and encode problems occurs.I am trying to solve this problem.thanks